# Kernel space write a file

Tags: c, linux-kernel, kernel

I'm trying to write a file **/proc/test/enable** in kernel 5.10 C code. 
I can write it in user space by calling fwrite.

When I using **kernel_write** in kernel C code, I will get the error **kernel write not supported for file test/enable and error code 22**.

```
struct file *filp;
char context[] = "test";
filp = filp_open("/proc/test/enable", O_WRONLY, 0);
int err = kernel_write(filp, (void *)context, sizeof(context), &filp->f_pos);
dev_info(afe->dev, "%s(), DONE, code = %d", __func__, err);
```

I can't understand why kernel_write can't get proc file write function, but userspace fwrite can

Comment: The proc filesystem is a virtual filesystem.

Comment: @stark so it is impossible to write proc file in kernel space? I saw that kernel_write / vfs_write / ksys_write all of them will check write function which will cause error

Comment: You don't need to "write proc" from kernel. All you need is to figure out which kernel api the desired proc file invokes and invoke that directly. Usually it's much easier (especially given that it appears to be your own custom code). :-)

Comment: Looks like a [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/) to me. If you wrote the module that exports `/proc/test/enable` then you don't need to open/write/close the file from kernel space, just change the variable in your module. If not, still you do not need to open/write/close from kernel, that is something that you almost *never* want to do, as it does very rarely make sense (and in this case it does not). Find the module implementing that proc functionality and look how you can access its functions or settings from within the kernel.

Answer (score 1):

For support "normal" write (from userspace), a file may define `.write` or `.write_iter` operations (in its `struct file_operations`).

But writing from the kernel can use **only** `.write_iter` operation.
For support writing your file from the kernel, you need to define `.write_iter` operation for the file **instead** of `.write` one.

---

The failed check for your case is

```
    /*
     * Also fail if ->write_iter and ->write are both wired up as that
     * implies very convoluted semantics.
     */
    if (unlikely(!file->f_op->write_iter || file->f_op->write))
        return warn_unsupported(file, "write");
```